# No Desktop after suspened or logged out 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, login-screen, desktop-environments, cinnamon

Ubuntu 14.04 w Cinnamon

When the system suspends or logs out sometimes(see time note below) the login menu does not reappear or sometimes the desktop and all features do not appear
and are not available.

So when you re login you have a blank screen, no wallpaper, no icons etc, can't run terminal or any hot keys and are forced to power button it. (Usually requires it to be logged out/suspended for 30 mins plus +/- )

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller

Comment: Is that Ivybridge?

Comment: yes ( and as I went to reply, as i was installing netbeans, mozilla in ubuntu wouldn't reply. so I had 2 run win7 VB 2 reply, lol)

Comment: Now, I am curious how you came across Cinnamon

Comment: I just stated that I am using cinnamon because I use a few applets

Comment: How did you install it.  What PPA did you use>

Comment: I can reproduce it.  Which means there is a bug in it or I do not know how to fix it

Comment: ppa:lestcape/cinnamon  vs 2.4.5  ( Sorry for the multiple edits, took me a min to realize a simple question )

Comment: The problem was with the unity ppa's n cinnamon's, not sure exactly y  but it was related to that. ( I ended up deleted the ppa's and replacing cinnamon with gnome which feels a lot more stable.